# How can I make the letters stop moving when I hover over them?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

What happens when I hover over the numbers:

https://gyazo.com/20b6426d435551c5ee238241d3f96b4d

Basically when I hover over the pagination numbers they move to the right and I don't know what I have done wrong in my code for them to do that. At the very bottom of the post I'll add an HTML that is basically only pagination but doesn't have this problem.

The Code:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Collapsible
            var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
            var i;

            for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
                coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                    this.classList.toggle("active");
                    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
                    if (content.style.maxHeight){
                        content.style.maxHeight = null;
                    } else {
                        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    <script>
      // Pagination
      pageSize = 20;

      var pageCount =  $(".line-content").length / pageSize;

         for(var i = 0 ; i<pageCount;i++){

           $("#pagin").append('<li><a href="#">'+(i+1)+'</a></li> ');
         }
            $("#pagin li").first().find("a").addClass("current")
        showPage = function(page) {
          $(".line-content").hide();
          $(".line-content").each(function(n) {
              if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
                  $(this).show();
          });
      }

      showPage(1);

      $("#pagin li a").click(function() {
          $("#pagin li a").removeClass("current");
          $(this).addClass("current");
          showPage(parseInt($(this).text()))
      });
    </script>
```

```
/* main.css */
body {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #999;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    margin: 0;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #999999;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #686868;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #4a4a4a;
}
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#main-header {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
}
#navbar {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
#navbar ul {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#navbar li {
    display: inline;
}
#navbar a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
#showcase {
    background-image: url('../images/background.jpg');
    background-position: center right;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
#showcase h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
#main {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 0 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#sidebar {
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    background: #444;
    color: #999;
    padding: 0px 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#main-footer {
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
@media(max-width:600px) {
    #main {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
    #sidebar {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

```
/* songscollapsible.css */
.current {
  color: inherit;
}
#pagin li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.collapsible {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #999;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
.content {
  max-height: 0;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #999;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: max-height 0.7s ease-out;
}
.button {
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px #555;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
/* .limg -> left image */
.limg {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
  max-width: 20px;
  max-height: 20px;
}
/* .fimg -> front image */
.fimg {
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  max-width: 20%;
}
.pl5 {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.pl40 {
  padding-left: 40%;
}
.lh1-4 {
  line-height: 1.4;
}
.dli {
  max-width: 17px;
  max-height: 17px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
}
```

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
      .current {
        color: inherit;
      }
      #pagin li {
        display: inline-block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="line-content">test1</div>
    <div class="line-content">test2</div>
    <div class="line-content">test3</div>
    <div class="line-content">test4</div>
    <div class="line-content">test5</div>
    <div class="line-content">test6</div>
    <ul id="pagin"></ul>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      // Pagination
      pageSize = 2;

      var pageCount =  $(".line-content").length / pageSize;

         for(var i = 0 ; i<pageCount;i++){

           $("#pagin").append('<li><a href="#">'+(i+1)+'</a></li> ');
         }
            $("#pagin li").first().find("a").addClass("current")
        showPage = function(page) {
          $(".line-content").hide();
          $(".line-content").each(function(n) {
              if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
                  $(this).show();
          });
      }

      showPage(1);

      $("#pagin li a").click(function() {
          $("#pagin li a").removeClass("current");
          $(this).addClass("current");
          showPage(parseInt($(this).text()))
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on hover they resize and push the other divs aside. You may try this convenient approach to resize them absolute:

```
a:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

or keep them as is:

```
a:hover {
    transform: scale(1.0);
}
```

(not sure which effect you want to achieve using `on:hover`

Comment: Tried it and nothing seems to change. Also `a:hover` is there because I have changed the colors of all text and I want it when you hover over links to not change color.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the position:fixed method, this should make the numbers cease to move if you hover over the numbers.

```html
<style>
a:hover {
  position:fixed;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I added that style to my code and this is the result.
https://gyazo.com/ea7ee57e05be2856257fa2e1679a20d3